# Template parameter pack's parameters to T

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map of components. Components are POD types that have some data. Each component has a unique identifier. The map can own only one component of a given type at any time. As such, I want to be able to query the map's owned components. This is the code I'm using to accomplish this:

```
template <typename T>
bool has()
{
    auto found = map.find(T::tag);
    if (found != map.end()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

This would result in awkward code like: `something.has<Component<int>>() && something.has<Component<float>>() ... etc;`

In order to make the code less messy, I want to make use of variadic templates.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool hasz()
{
    has<T>();
    has<Args>()...; /* expected ‘;’ before ‘...’ token */
}
```

---

Shouldn't `has<Args>()...` expand to (pseudo) `has<Args[0]>(), has<Args[1]>(), etc...` (which would be legal syntax)? And is it possible to do this at all?

Comment: Pack expansion is only allowed where `,` (the comma) can not possibly refer to the comma-operator.

Comment: `auto list = { has<Args>()... };` and `#include <initializer_list>`. Then you can iterat it to find if any element is `true`.

Comment: @jrok, thank you. Both yours and Manu's solutions work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you only have to call the function recursivelly:

```
template <typename T>
bool has()
{
    return map.end() != map.find(T::tag);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool has()
{
    return has<T>() && has<Args...>();
}
```

#### How it works?

You have two versions of the function: One with one parameter, and one with n parameters. The first is used as the base case, and the later is used as the recursive case.
So if you do this:

```
has<bool,int,char,float>();
```

The trace is:

> call to `has<bool,int,char,float>()` (Call to recursive case)
>   call to `has<bool,int,char>()` (Call to recursive case)
>   call to `has<bool,int>()` (Call to recursive case)
>   call to `has<bool>()` (Call to base case)

**NOTE:** Of course this example does not work really, because the types I used in the example don't have a `::tag` member. Its only an example of the call trace indeed.
In addition, I have simplified the trace to not overcomplicate the example. The true trace will be:

> call to `has<bool,int,char,float>()` (Call to recursive case)
>   ....call to `has<bool>()` (Call to base case)     //left side of the &&
>   ....call to `has<int,char,float>()` (Call to recursive case)    //right side of the &&
>   ........call to `has<int>()` (Call to base case)   //left side of the &&
>   ........call to `has<char,float>()` (Call to recursive case)       //right side of the &&
>   ............call to `has<char>()` (Call to base case) //left side of the &&
>   ............call to `has<float>()` (Call to base case)              //right side of the &&

Comment: Maybe I should re-name myself to "World's Worst *Researcher". I was looking for a solution for a day, but still couldn't find it. :) Thank you. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @World'sWorstCoder thats only a bad day, not a bad programmer

Comment: Thanks @R.MartinhoFernandes, I'm the World's Worst Editer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::min`:

```
#include<algorithm>

template <typename... Args>
bool hasz()
{
    return std::min({has<Args>()...});
}
```

Note that this doesn't have short-circuit behavior - it will always evaluate `has<Args>` for all arguments. If it's the problem, then use recursive version.